# Mass of 3 notebooks and a box

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, word-problem

I can't seem to figure this out.

> The mass of 3 notebooks and 1 box is 610g. Each notebook is 250g lighter than the box.
>   What is the mass of each notebook?

This seems to be $3(x-250)+x=610$. So, $$3x-750+x=610\implies 4x-750=610\implies 4x=1360\implies x=1360/4 = 340$$

Which seems to be impossible, since $3x$ (if each $x$ is $340$) is more than 610g.

Comment: don't mess up variables. x stands for box

Comment: If you are going to use "algebra" to solve such a problem, the solution should always begin with something like "Let $x$ be the mass of the box" or "Let $y$ be the mass of a notebook." This will tell the reader what's going on. At least as importantly, it will **you** keep track.

Comment: +1 for showing your work.  It allows a much more specific answer

Answer (score 5):

You set up the problem correctly, but $x$ stands for the mass of the *box* in your equation, not the mass of a notebook.

We have that
$$3\cdot(340-250)+340=3\cdot 90+340=270+340=610.$$